# GitLab CI with r testthat package

Tags: r, gitlab, testthat

Can anyone run testthat tests for a minimal R package using GitLab.com continuous integration tools? 
My attempt:
https://gitlab.com/djchapman/CI_example
This is the .gitlab-CI.yml text I am using,

```
image: rocker/rstudio
test:
   script:
    - R -e 'install.packages(c("devtools", "testthat"))'
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - R -e 'devtools::test()'
```

It is adapted from [this](https://bertelsen.ca/example-gitlab-ci-yml-for-r-projects/) website. I realize that devtools has dependencies which may need to be included as packages are installed, and I tried that, but the libraries for git2r didn't seem to install correctly, and now I wonder if I'm going about it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Why do you call `devtools::test()`? Checking a package includes running the tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to run the tests via `devtools` since `R CMD check` does that already. The following should work:

```
image: rocker/rstudio
test:
   script:
    - R -e 'install.packages(c("testthat"))'
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
```

Alternatively you could use an image that allows for binary installs:

```
image: rocker/r-base
test:
   script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends r-cran-testthat r-cran-devtools
    - R -e "devtools::install_deps()"
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
```

This is useful if you have dependencies that have not been packaged for Debian, or if you don't want to update your CI script when you add a new dependency.

Comment: Thank you Ralf! I tested both solutions and they passed. I did not fully understand R CMD check, and am inexperienced with yaml.

Comment: Noting that it should read `"devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"` if you have any tests that rely on packages that are in the suggests section of your DESCRIPTION file. The default behaviour is to ignore packages that are suggested.

Answer (score 2):

For me this didn't work as expected. I found out that the problem was I had vignettes. Using the following content of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I worked around that problem:

```
image: rocker/r-base
gitlab:
   script:
    - apt-get update
    # install dependencies for package
    - apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends r-cran-xml2 r-cran-testthat r-cran-devtools
    - R -e 'devtools::install_deps(dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))'
    # remove vignettes folder and get VignetteBuilder field out of DESCRIPTION file
    - rm -rf vignettes
    - R -e 'd <- read.dcf("DESCRIPTION"); d[, colnames(d) == "VignetteBuilder"] <- NA; write.dcf(d, "DESCRIPTION")'
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --as-cran
    # update code coverage
    - apt-get install --yes git
    - R -e "covr::codecov(token = 'mytoken')"
```

It removes the vignettes folder and removes the `VignetteBuilder` field from the `DESCRIPTION` file before it starts building. Quite convenient, although I now cannot test the contents of it.

After a while I found out that `covr::codecov()` works really well if you give the token as input (from https://codecov.io/gl/yourname/yourproject/settings) and install `git` on beforehand.